# finishActivity (int requestCode) not working

Tags: android, start-activity

I start an activity using the following code for a given result:

```
startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(
        getActivity(),
        StudentDetails.class
    ).putExtra(
        GeneralFunctions.EXTRA_STUDENT_ID,
        (String) studentsListInUse.get(index)
                                  .valueForKey(GeneralFunctions.STUDENT_ID)
    ),
    GeneralFunctions.REQUEST_STUDENTS_EDITING
);
```

Then in some other point I finish it:

```
finishActivity(GeneralFunctions.REQUEST_STUDENTS_EDITING);
```

And start it again with another student´s data:

```
startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(
        this,
        StudentDetails.class
    ).putExtra(
        GeneralFunctions.EXTRA_STUDENT_ID,
        (String) attendance.valueForKey(GeneralFunctions.STUDENT_ID)
    ),
    GeneralFunctions.REQUEST_STUDENTS_EDITING
);
```

The problem is, when I go back the screens, every single activity displaying student´s details remain on the stack. In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) there's nothing besides:

> The request code of the activity that you had given to
>   startActivityForResult(). If there are multiple activities started
>   with this request code, they will all be finished.

So what extra detail is missing here? It should simply finish all activities that were started with a given resultCode.

Comment: I found a solution for what I needed. Using the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. It worked even a little better than finishing an activity for a given result would. But I still dont know why finishActivity wont work.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution but I've been looking at this trying to figure out why. I've never used that method but I wonder if you only had one instance of that child activity if it would make a difference. Also, are you calling `setResult()` in the child Activity?

Comment: Child activity being the one that is suposed to be finished? I had just one instance of it before starting the second and calling finishActivity. Otherwise both would be terminated. And no, I didnt called setResult. Would that make a difference? FinishActivity cant finish an activity wich result hadnt been set?

Comment: As I said, I've never used it so I don't know for sure. So, I was just thinking of things that *may* make a difference, though the docs didn't indicate such an issue.